# All of the Bluetooth Beacon samples of Rad Pack Seattle fails

Tags: android, delphi, crash, bluetooth-lowenergy, sample

I am trying to learn bluetooth Beacon with Rad Pack Seattle. So I try out all the beacon samples, but none of them seems to work. I tried all 6 of them on three different Pc's (2 Windows 7 and one Server 2012) running the code on 4 different android smartphones (LG and Nokia). I installed new versions of Seattle on all of the Pc's.
Most of the samples fail within a few seconds. Sometimes they freeze, sometimes they crash, one of them seems to run but its just not seeing the beacons I am directing it to (And I know it works since I have some finished programs that will find the beacons I want it to) etc. One of them, the simplest one I think (It only has like 12 lines), fails with a message about "duplicates record".

So I am starting to think there is something wrong with the Rad Pack Seattle. But that cannnot be true, so I guess it must be me doing something. But what? Unfortunately there are very few to ask.

If I am asking in the wrong place, please point me in the right direction.

Any hint will be appreciated - a lot. ;-)

PoulK

This is the **Simple Beacon Demo**

> Blockquote

```
Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, System.Beacon, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Memo,
  System.Beacon.Components, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.ScrollBox;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Beacon1: TBeacon;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Beacon1BeaconEnter(const Sender: TObject; const ABeacon: IBeacon; const CurrentBeaconList: TBeaconList);
    procedure Beacon1BeaconExit(const Sender: TObject; const ABeacon: IBeacon; const CurrentBeaconList: TBeaconList);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Beacon1BeaconEnter(const Sender: TObject; const ABeacon: IBeacon;
  const CurrentBeaconList: TBeaconList);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('New Beacon');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format( 'UUID: %s Major: %d Minor: %d',[ABeacon.GUID.ToString, ABeacon.Major, ABeacon.Minor]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Current Beacons count :' + Length(CurrentBeaconList).toString);
end;

procedure TForm1.Beacon1BeaconExit(const Sender: TObject; const ABeacon: IBeacon; const CurrentBeaconList: TBeaconList);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Beacon exited');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format( 'UUID: %s Major: %d Minor: %d',[ABeacon.GUID.ToString, ABeacon.Major, ABeacon.Minor]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Current Beacons count :' + Length(CurrentBeaconList).toString);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Beacon1.Enabled := True;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Obvious point but have you granted both location and bluetooth permissions?

Comment: By location permission, you mean the android permissions to determine and/or report it?
Actually, I think not, I didnt think it would be necessary. But I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

According to Embarcadero's documentation (below), Bluetooth Beacon seems to be supported only starting from Windows 10.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_Beacons

That explains the case with Windows 7 (also happened to me; then I tried a couple ones on Windows 10 and found that they could work, detecting the beacons).
Unfortunately, there seems to be no info about the minimum version of Windows Server.

Looking at the version number that says 10.0* in the table in Microsoft’s documentation (below), maybe it needs minimum Windows Server 2016.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/operating-system-version

For more info (if it can be of any help), I am using Delphi 10.2 (Tokyo) on 64-bit Windows 10.

The sample project that I tried is 'AllBeaconsScanner'. It was running okay, after being built with target platform 64-bit Windows.

On my machine the path to the sample project is as below.
`C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Device Sensors and Services\Bluetooth\Beacons\ExtendedBeaconScanner`

Comment: Okay. I now tried it with windows 10, and they still all fail. But this is a Windows 10 32 bit. In any case, this is android code, so if I understand you correctly, it is the compiler that malfunctions on Windows 7?
In any case, I'll get myself a Windows 10 64 bit tomorrow. Maybe a new Pc as well? (Yes, I'm becoming paranoid)

Thank you very much

PoulK

Comment: I have now tried to install a Rad 10.4 and this version told me it would not run on 32-bit Windows. 
So, I'm off to get me a Windows 10 64 bit tomorrow.

Thanks a lot

Comment: For more info (if it can be of any help), I am using Delphi 10.2 (Tokyo) on 64-bit Windows 10.


The sample project that I tried is 'AllBeaconsScanner'. It was running okay, after being built with target platform 64-bit Windows.


On my machine the path to the sample project is as below.
`C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Multi-Device Samples\Device Sensors and Services\Bluetooth\Beacons\ExtendedBeaconScanner`

Comment: AllBeaconsScanne, for me it works very well under windows 10, but on android it does not detect beacons.  Does anyone know why? I have a Samsung 10 and Delphi 10.4. The BeaconScope application from google play detects without any problem